# ObservableCollection vs INotifyCollectionChanged in UWP with MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

So im stood in a situation, where i have a main XML file with data. That data file i then convert into a List so i can access the data in my program.

So for now i can get that data showed, but i dont know how to filter it and get that filteret version shown.

So lets say i have a list of recipes. Now i want to see all the recipes with lettuce in. How do i go about that?

I understand that i need a MVVM setup, and i have that, but its static, given that i right now only have one list created when the view is made. So if i hard code i only want to see lettuce, i can do that, but how do i go about making a button for that? Or even better a search box?
Iv'e tried to look into ObservableCollections or INotifyCollectionChanged, but i am unsure what will actually lead to what i need.

What would be the best approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "So i found out a solution to my problem." - fine, but then post it as a self-answer, don't add it to the question. See the site guidelines.

Comment: Didn't realise. Iv'e done that here, and to the other posts where i had made same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out a solution to my problem.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Person>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <FirstName>Frank</FirstName>
        <LastName>Heist</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>Calder</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
        <LastName>Calder</LastName>
    </Person>

</List>
```

Models > Data.cs

```
 public class dataRaw
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class collectionGenerator
    {
       public static List<dataRaw> getList()
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
            var dataList = doc.Root
                .Descendants("Person")
                .Select(node => new dataRaw
                {
                    data = node.Element("Number").Value,
                    firstName = node.Element("FirstName").Value,
                    lastName = node.Element("LastName").Value,
                })
            .ToList();
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<dataRaw> t1;
        public List<dataRaw> t3;
        public ObservableCollection<dataRaw> t2;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            t1 = collectionGenerator.getList();
            t2 = new ObservableCollection<dataRaw>(t1);
        }

        private void Filter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            t1 = collectionGenerator.getList();
            t2.Clear();
            string data = TB1.Text;

            if(data != "")
            {
            var Vtest = from VT in t1
                        where VT.firstName == data || VT.lastName == data
                        select VT;
                foreach (var VT in Vtest)
                {
                    t2.Add(new dataRaw { data = "1", firstName = VT.firstName, lastName = VT.lastName });

                }
            }
            else
            {
                var Vtest = from VT in t1
                            where VT.data == "1"
                            select VT;
                foreach (var VT in Vtest)
                {
                    t2.Add(new dataRaw { data = "1", firstName = VT.firstName, lastName = VT.lastName });

                }
            }
          }
        }
```

xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind t2}" Grid.Row="1">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:dataRaw">
                    <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Width="200" FontSize="48" Text="{x:Bind firstName}" Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="200"  FontSize="48" Text="{x:Bind lastName}" Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Row="1"/>

                    </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>

        <Button Content="Filter" Name="Filter" FontSize="36" Click="Filter_Click" Width="200" Height="100" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Name="TB1" Height="100" Width="400" Grid.Row="2" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Do realize that there's not a trace of MVVM in here. Worth reading up on that.

Comment: Okay. Can i change the heading of the post?

Comment: Yes, but don't. It's still part of the question, just not of the answer.

Comment: Arh, got it. But yeah, i have no idea what makes up the MVVM part then :P

Answer (score 0):

You need an observable collection here as you want to bind view's listview,for example, to a collection in viewmodel. To be able to change the view depending on search filter, you can pass a searchString parameter from a textbox in view to view model. In the passed string filter property, filter the collection as well using Linq or other means. And as this collection in viewmodel is bound to View's List, it will update the view when the collection is changed (that is the functionality of observablecollection).

Comment: When you replace the entire List at once it doesn't have to be an Observable.

Comment: Thanks for adding your useful comment.

Comment: Mine or Henks? Iv'e just been told off for not doing like you are supposed to in here. So i need to see if i did it right this time.